# What are differences between fixed buffers, and using the `MarshalAs` attr, with `UnmanagedType.ByValArray`?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Well, there are some obvious differences:
fixed buffer:

- they must be declared in unsafe block (implying that the whole project must be compiled with `-unsafe` switch).
- for using the fixed buffer, the containing object must be fixed,

using `MarshalAs` attribute:

- although the size is given to the marshaller, there is no guaranty that the actual array would have sufficient element count, nor that it's not null.
- the array could be used simply and intuitively as any other array.

But what I cannot find answer for, is why fixed buffer are needed in the first place?
When one must use them?
Why one would want to use it, assuming one can validate the size of regular managed array?

I can think of performance constraints, that might make one choose fixed buffer over regular arrays...
Is that all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Performance is the main reason. For a single struct with a fixed length array, it's probably no a big deal. But for a huge array of such structs then pinned rather than marshalling could be a massive perf gain. +1 for asking the question

Comment: That's what I thought, but I couldn't find any good answer for that (so I asked :) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, efficiency is certainly the primary reason.  When you apply `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` then the struct must *always* be marshaled.  In other words, the CLR is forced to create a new copy of the struct and initialize it with the values from the managed struct since the unmanaged layout of the struct is different.  That can be avoided when you use a fixed buffer, provided the other members of the struct are blittable as well.  In which case the CLR can simply pass a pointer to the struct.  Much faster of course.

There are a few interop scenarios where you *must* use a fixed size buffer.  Typically when the array member is misaligned, that violates the atomicity guarantee of the .NET memory model.   Or you declare a union (fields overlap each other) and the CLR objects against overlapping a field of a reference type with a field of a value type.  That's incompatible with the garbage collector, it cannot reliably detect the object pointer.  You'll get a TypeLoadException at runtime when that's the case.

Both scenarios are fundamentally unverifiable.  It is always unsafe if the native code writes back to the struct, memory corruption occurs when it writes past the end of the array.  Extremely hard to diagnose.  The need to explicitly use the *unsafe* keyword when you use a fixed size buffer only applies to the lack of index checking when you access the fixed size buffer in your C# code.